# How to stop windows from redirecting after it satisfy an if statement using Javascript

Tags: javascript

```
function validationAlert() {
var trCount = document.body.querySelectorAll('tr').length
 if(trCount<4)
{
    alert(trCount);
     alert('There is something wrong to your data please try again');
     //code here to stop page from redirecting
}

}
```

Can you help me to stop the page from redirecting?

Comment: This script does not redirect anywhere. Is this all of your code?

Comment: If there's another piece of code that's redirecting, alter that, don't try to stop the code with more code.

Answer (score 0):

You can either not write the code which will redirect or write a return statement which will make rest of the code in that function unreachable.